# Reading Excel Files/win32com.client

Tags: python, win32com

I am writing a code where I link Excel into PSSE. I am using the `win32` module because my school does not allow use of the modules `xlrd`, `openpyxl`, and `csv`. So my goal in the code was to initially read the excel file using `win32` module.

It read the files but I am trying to do the following:

- read the first column so it would represent the *year*
- second column is *bus number*
- third column is *bus name*
- fourth column is *Power*
- sixth column is *Area*
- last column is *location ID*.

I have posted a snippet of the excel sheet of the format of my page. My next goal is to link year and location together as the criteria for finding the *busnum, busname,* and *power*. I would use a `raw_input()` for the *year* and the *location* and if *location* and *year* are entered, the output should give me the *bus number*, *bus name*, and *power*.

My code is shown below and this is was my idea for doing code. It does not run and I tried everything and nothing works.

[image: Excel Sheet]

```
import os, sys
import psspy
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

PSSE_LOCATION = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE33\PSSBIN"
sys.path.append(PSSE_LOCATION)
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ';' + PSSE_LOCATION

xlApp = Dispatch ("Excel.Application")   #Calls for Excel
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('Load forecast 12152016.xlsx')    #It finds the workbook
xlSht = xlWb.Worksheets (18)   
dataList = []

for row in range (2,760): #It goes through the 758 items in A and B
    for col in (1,2,3,4,5):
         dataList.append(xlSht.Cells(row,col))

mydict = {}
for row in dataList:
    year = xlSht.Cells[1:760,1]
    busnnum = row[B2:B760]
    busname = row[C2:C760]
    Power = row[D2:D760]
    Area = row[E2:E760]
    location = row[F2:F760]

# convert the types from string to Python numbers

change= float(change)
bus = int(busnum)

#If this is a year not seen before, add it to the dictionary
if year not in mydict:
    mydict[year] = {}

busses_in_year = mydict[year]
if location not in busses_in_year:
    busses_in_year[location] = []


 #Add the bus to the list of busses that stop at this location
busses_in_year[location].append((busnum,busname,power))

year = raw_input("Please Select Year of Study: ")
print("\n")

commands = ["M", "As", "Br", "D",
            "V", "G","W","E","S","E",
            "Ea","DU","Cor","Asto",
            "AV","A"]
max_columns = 50

for index, commands in enumerate(commands):
    stars_amount = max(max_columns - len(commands), 0)
    row = "# {} {}({})".format(commands, "." * stars_amount, index + 1)
    print row

    location=raw_input(" \n The list above show the TLA Pockets as well as the ID numbers assigned to them ()\n\n Please enter the ID #: ")
    print("\n")


# assume CSV has columns as described in the doc string
if year in mydict and location in mydict[year]:  
    busses_in_year = mydict[year]
    print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
    print("\n")

    for busnum,busname,change in busses_in_year[location]:
        change= float(change)
        busnum = int(busnum)
        print('Bus #: %d' % busnum ,'Area Station: %s'% busname, 'New_load: %d MW' %change)


        psspy.bsys(1,0,[0.0,0.0],0,[],1,[busnum],0,[],0,[])
        psspy.scal_2(1,0,1,[0,0,0,0,0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
        psspy.scal_2(0,1,2,[0,1,0,1,0],[change,0.0,0,-.0,0.0,-.0,0])
```

Comment: are you allowed to use the `pandas` package?  Reading your data into Python's memory with `pd.read_excel()` is very easy.